# Происхождение слова "пупс"

Tags: этимология

Почему кукол, изображающих младенцев, называют "пупсы", "пупсики"? Что это за слово и откуда вообще взялось?
Спасибо

Answer (score 6, accepted):

От английского "pup" - малыш?

Answer (score 2):

От немецкого "Puppe" - кукла, манекен, куколка.

Answer (score 0):

У них, как правило, была встроена "свистулька". Давишь на резиновый животик и раздаётся "свист", похожий на ... пук. А пукать по немецки "pupsen" и, соответственно, звук "Pups"